# admin-on-rest: How to pass custom parameters to authClient

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

In admin-on-rest framework, the default authClient doesn't seem to have the ability to accept custom parameters such as url. The following url explained how to use authClient, but the example shows the url has to be part of authClient.js.

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Authentication.html

when I try to specify a custom argument (url) in App.js,

```
const api = 'http://10.1.16.138:8343/rest/...', 

<Admin ... authClient={authClient(api)}>
    ...
</Admin>
```

and add this paratermer in authClient.js,

```
export default (url, type, params) => {

...
const request = new Request(url, {...});
```

The authClient no longer works.

Is there a way to allow custom parameter without building a custom login page? If custom page has to be done, any suggestion on how to tweak authClient.js?

Comment: You could add some more details, including code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your auth client, try replacing

```
export default (url, type, params) => {
```

By

```
export default url => (type, params) => {
```

It's not admin-on-rest, it's just JS.

Comment: I agree this is just part of my JS learning. Thank you for helping even when it's not really admin-on-rest!